# Automatically Input string 'TOTALS' into the immediate left cell corresponding to AutoSum cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a SUM sub which generates the AutoSum in the immediate blank cell after all the records, Now i need to Input string 'TOTALS' into  the immediate left cell corresponding to AutoSum cell. The Autosum sub code is as below

```
Sub AddSum()
   Dim rng As Range
   For Each rng In Range("J:J").SpecialCells(xlConstants).Areas
      rng.Offset(rng.Count).Resize(1, 1).Formula = "=sum(" & rng.Address & ")"
   Next rng
End Sub
```

the 'TOTALS' should be like this below, in K column next to J column and its cell position is only known after the AutoSum is gen

[image]

Comment: `rng.Offset(rng.Count,-1).Resize(1, 1).Value= "TOTALS"`

Comment: @ScottCraner - Too good. Perfect, it works like a charm :) :) Thank you so much, Also how to make its Font BOLD and color of that  cell background as Grey

Comment: You now know how to reference the correct cell.  A couple of quick google searches should show you how to do the formatting.

Comment: i know how to conditional format a fixed cell, but as this s dynamic, i am strugging. let me explore, if i can conditional format a cell based on its value TOTALS

Comment: Record a macro while applying the formatting - it will give you what you need.